# true or false checkbox javascript

Tags: javascript

¿el input checkbox tiene asignado true o false por defecto o se lo tengo que asignar? si es así, ¿cómo se hace? en javascript.
gracias

```
 <div class="fullday">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
 <div>
```

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir con "tiene asignado true o false"? ¿si está seleccionado por defecto? ¿cuál es su valor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<label for="myCheck">Checkbox:</label> 
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">

<p id="text" style="display:none">Checkbox esta funcionando!</p>
```

En el siguiente código se crea la función validar_check. Si se hace click en checkbox entonces muéstrame el texto con el id "text". Sino ocúltalo.

```
<script>
function validar_check() {
  var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "block";
  } else {
     text.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

Aquí puedes añadir tus funciones y lo que necesites con javascript.

Answer (score 0):

En un elemento checkbox podés consultar si está "checked" de la siguiente manera ej:

HTML

```
 <div class="fullday">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
 <div>
```

Script

```
if (document.getElementById('check').checked)
{
// Hacer algo si está seleccionado. Ej:
alert("fue seleccionado")
}
```

Esto lo puedes lanzar por ejemplo llamando a una función con un evento onchange del checkbox.

ej:

```
const checkbox = document.getElementById('check');

checkbox.addEventListener("change", validarCheckbox, false);

function validarCheckbox()
{
  if(checkbox.checked){
    alert('checkbox esta seleccionado');
  } else {
    alert('checkbox NO esta seleccionado');
}
}
```

O puedes sencillamente desde el html usar por ejemplo:

```
 <div class="fullday">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check" onchange="validarCheckbox()">
 <div>
```

Y en JS podrías usar algo así:

```
function validarCheckbox()
const checkbox = document.getElementById('check');
{
  if(checkbox.checked){
    alert('checkbox esta seleccionado');
  } else {
    alert('checkbox NO esta seleccionado');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El elemento checkbox **es por defecto `false`**, mientras no aclaremos otra cosa en el HTML. La propiedad que hay que analizar es `checked`. Si no está presente es `false`, si está presente es `true`. Hay una tercera posibilidad: `indeterminate` que al momento no lo implementa ningún navegador.

```js
check = document.getElementById("check");


check.addEventListener("click", function() {

  console.log("estado al hacer check o uncheck", this.checked);

})


console.log("estado inicial:", check.checked);// <-- false por defecto
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check">
```

Si queremos que por defecto sea `true` hay que agregar `checked` en el HTML:

```js
check = document.getElementById("check");


check.addEventListener("click",function(){

console.log("estado al hacer check o uncheck",this.checked);

})


console.log("estado inicial:",check.checked);// <-- ahora es true por defecto
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check" checked>
```

El `.value` en este caso es simplemente el valor que se enviará cuando se envíe un formulario, si es que `.checked` es `true`.

Answer (score -1):

El *input* de tipo *checkbox* no tiene un valor booleano asignado por defecto, si te puede interesar recuperar su estado para trabajar con él (si fue o no seleccionado).

Se puede comprobar con JavaScript un checkbox:

```html
<div class="fullday">
    <input type="checkbox" id="check">
<div>
<script>
    window.onload = () => {

        function qs(strSelector) // js node
        {
            return document.querySelector(strSelector);
        }

        const input = qs('#check');
        console.log(input, input.value, input.checked, 777);
    };
</script>
```

Obtendríamos:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check"> 'on' false 777
```

En *Chrome* no estaría seleccionado por defecto, ni tiene un valor diferente de 'on'*.
Como valor se le puede asociar algún dato, si se usa como parte de un formulario **solo los checkboxes seleccionados se envían**.

En JS puedes saber si un checkbox esta o no seleccionado o cambiar su estado con `checked`, por ejemplo si amplio el ejemplo, un botón cambia el estado:

```html
<div class="fullday">
        <input type="checkbox" id="check">
    <div>
    <button type="button">Seleccionar / deseccionar</button>

    <script>
        window.onload = () => {

            function qs(strSelector) // js node
            {
                return document.querySelector(strSelector);
            }

            const input = qs('#check');
            console.log(input, input.value, input.checked, 777);

            qs('button').addEventListener('click', function()
            {
                input.checked = !input.checked;
            });
        };
    </script>
```